# Is measurable temperature only due to average translational energy in diatomic gases or solids?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Assumptions:

1. Ensemble with Translational, Vibrational and Rotational degree of freedoms.
2. Not classical, but discrete energy states.

I can't find an clear explanation in kinetic theory of thermodynamics what the measurable temperature is. Some sources state, it's only the average kinetic energy of translation, while other state it's the average kinetic energy of all degree of freedoms.

- If we look at a diatomic gas at T=0, there is still a Zero-Point
  rotatitional energy $\frac{h \times v}{2}$. If the measurable
  temperature would be caused by all average kinetic energys, it
  couldn't be 0 because there would still be K.E. of rotation (even if
  it's very very small,... well as small as it would ever get).
- If measurable temperature would not just be due to average K.E. energy of translation, I assume we wouldn't observe the changes in specific heat capacity with rising temperature. Rising temperature causes rotational and vibrational states to "unfreeze", I assume those are only internal ways of storing energy, which doesn't show up in temperature.

Those were 2 reasons I tend to believe that measurable Temperature is only due to average translational energy. But imagine the following:

- Reaching the point of energy states, where the gaps of possible translational states is greater than that of rotation (translation is dense at the beginning and tends to separate further apart, while rotation is far apart at the beginning but comes closer together).

If we now a pump a little more energy in that system, we couldn't measure any temperature change for a small interval, because now the energy first populates rotational states which doesn't show up in temperature. Temperature first starts to change again, if the the gap is bridged where the next higher translational state could be populated. So wouldn't that mean, that we can't determine internal energy in that Intervall with temperature measurement? There could be a small variation of internal energy with no change in temperature at all.

To explain, why I added "solids" in my title, one might argue, that a solid can't have translational energy and thus it's a proof, that also other kind of degree of freedoms contribute to temperature.
I think, there is also translational movement in a solid, which is different to the common vibrational degree of freedom. For me, vibration is the movement due to bond length variation of the molecule within (the mass point remains the same), while translation occurs in a more restricted way: Moleculs as a whole "vibrate" around a point and thus there is a variation of the mass point.

Edit: I mean, in some textbooks they define an extra *vibrational temperature* or *rotational temperature* and compare it to *normal temperature* but what should *normal* even mean? Average K.E. of translational?

Comment: *Classically*, you've got equipartition, from which it follows that temperature is related to the *total* kinetic energy per particle (assuming no internal degrees of freedom like vibrational) that includes both translational and rotational kinetic energy, so no matter what, that had better pop out at high enough temperatures.

Comment: @march classically, equipartion tells me, that any degree of freedom is as likely as any other and thus it doesn't matter which degree of freedom I observe to determine internal energy because all have the same average kinetic energy. That's why I excluded it in my assumption, also I exclude the possibility of tremendous high temperature because even with discrete energy levels they would have the same average K.E. temperature and I don't want that equipartition argument in an answers.

Answer (score 2):

Temperature relates in an indirect way to average energy, but it is not simply equal to average energy except in a few simple cases. A more general way to express the relationship between temperature and energy is the formula
$$
P = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-E/k_B T}.
$$
Here $P$ is the probability that a small subsystem (such as a single molecule or a small part of a gas) is in a state of energy $E$ when the whole system is in thermal equilibrium at temperature $T$. $Z$ is a normalization constant whose value is such that the sum of the probabilities over all available states is equal to 1. Finally, $k_B$ is a fundamental constant called Boltzmann's constant.

If we use this formula to work out the average energy of subsystems (such as single molecules) then the answer will be related to $T$. If a gas is hot and only has translational kinetic energy then the mean energy per atom is $(3/2) k_B T$, for example. If a gas has diatomic molecules and is at ordinary temperatures the sum of the translational and rotational energy per molecule is $(5/2) k_B T$ over a fairly broad range of temperature, but not for all temperatures. In this second example both the translational motion and the rotational motion have thermal energy and the distribution of probability is given by the above formula, so both can be assigned a temperature. In thermal equilibrium, both have the same temperature. So when you measure the temperature of a gas you are measuring the temperature of the translational motion and of the rotational motion and vibrational motion etc. But which of these motions affects your thermometer most readily will depend on the type of thermometer. An ordinary thermometer responds mostly to the impact of the molecules via their translational kinetic energy. But by using laser beams it is possible to measure the rotational temperature without being sensitive to the translational temperature.

Finally, a system at zero temperature can still have lots of energy. It has all of its rest-mass energy, for example. It has all the potential energy of the inter-atomic bonds, and of the electrons in the atoms, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful clarification. Just to make sure: If a book states that at T=0, there is still rotational energy, then T=0 is the case of an thermometer which is most likely only affected by translational movement I assume? T ≠ 0 if that "thermometer" could also be affected by rotation?

Comment: I think my confusion was rooted in the way, that some sources didn't make an distinction between how we commonly measure temperature and others did - like "..and the temperature as ordinarily measured does not account for molecular rotation and vibration." from http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/kintem.html#c1 I couldn't really work with the information "ordinarily measure".

Comment: "So when you measure the temperature of a gas you are measuring the temperature of the translational motion and of the rotational motion and vibrational motion etc.", also the electronic excitement states, which get relevant in very high temperatures? Thuse aren't really stable and I don't know, if they have some kind of K.E. which could be transferred to other instances in my ensemble but in the study of partition function they also come up.